# How to insert records chunk by chunk in Vertica

Tags: vertica

I have a CSV file containing large amount of data.

I am trying bulk insert by chunks.

Is it possible to insert 1000 records from that CSV file using COPY command of Vertica? And looping every 1000 records then next.

I am using :

`copy bulk from local 'C:\FileUpload\bulk.csv' 
delimiter ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
null as ''
exceptions 'C:\FileUpload\bulk.log'`

Thanks

Comment: What is the scope? Getting 1k element per (initial) ROS container or what?

Comment: Just want to loop and insert the data in database... either 1000 at a time or more.

Comment: There's no point in "looping". Just COPY your file and let Vertica decide how to parse & merge it. Consider that V is going to re-organize your (columns based) ROS containers even if you commit every X rows. For very small input files (thousands of rows) using TRICKLE to load in the WOS is probably a good idea.